# How can I combine two columns from a csv as x-axis for my ggplot in python?

Tags: python, ggplot2

I have a CSV file with multiple columns. I want to combine two columns and use them as my x-axis in a plot.

```
    ###################################
    # Book_nr # Page_nr #  Word_count #
    ###################################
    #    1    #    1    #     380     #
    #    1    #    2    #     425     #
    #    1    #    3    #     290     #
    #    2    #    1    #     520     #
    #    2    #    2    #     402     #
    ###################################
```

At the moment I create a simple plot with Book_br and Word_count on x- and y-axis

```py
data = read_csv('file')
p = ggplot(aes(x='Book_nr', y='Word_count'), data=data) + geom_point()
```

I want to use the Book_nr and the Page_nr on my x-axis to show how many words are on each page. So basically I want to plot Tuples like this: `(x,y) -> ((1,1),380),((1,2),425),((1,3),290),((2,1),520),((2,2),402)`

When I rewrite the csv and merge both columns by hand, I can plot it like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcgpt.png).

Comment: You need a single numerical value to plot against.  For instance, you could use the sum, the average, the min, or the max of the two values.  Another option would be to make a 3D plot with `Book_nr` on the x axis, `Page_nr` on the y axis, and `Word_count` on the z axis.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion would be to use `facet_wrap`.

```
g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Page_nr, y = Word_Count))
g <- g + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
g <- facet_wrap(~Book_nr)
```

Comment: That splits the plot into subplots for every book. This will not scale with a huge amount of books. What I look for is something like the ability to plot a date on the x-axis, but split it in month & year to improve visibility. For my case its the other way round: I have a book and a page which should be combined (and ordered) for my x-axis.